# Remove line break but keep javascript format

Tags: php, preg-replace

Below is code how i remove multiple spaces from the buffer :

```
function removeWhitespace($buffer)
{
   return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $buffer);
}

ob_start('removeWhitespace');

//html source code

ob_get_flush();
```

with this code, my html source code will become one line(compress) but it's will break javascript code :

**Before**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
        overlayClose: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        rel: "colorbox"
    });
});
//--></script>
```

**After**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- $(document).ready(function() { $('.colorbox').colorbox({ overlayClose: true, opacity: 0.5, rel: "colorbox" }); }); //--></script>
```

then the javascript will not work anymore, so how to ignore if detect this `<!--` or maybe just skip if detect javascript ?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the whitespace?

Comment: Removing whitespaces from javascript code should not break it and in fact your code checks out as valid.

Comment: @Blender im using PageSpeed and one of suggestion is "Compacting HTML code..bla..." and this extension also show optimize code that remove whitespace/space ... so i just try to optimize my html source code..

Comment: @rusly this is micro optimization..brings nothing but turns debugging into a nightmare. use gzip transfer if you need to decrease the html document size

Comment: use `\h` instead of `\s`

Comment: @hek2mgl seems legit , but i just try to follow what google.com homepage does..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negative look-behind:

```
preg_replace('/(?!<!--)\s+/', ' ', $buffer);
```